# java reflections to get all user created class variables only

Tags: java, class, generics, reflection, javabeans

I am trying to use reflections to create a function that checks all custom made class variables to see if they have valid values based on pattern "[0-9a-zA-Z_]+"

I found some code templates and adapted to my code and looks like this

```
UserClass uc = new UserClass();
Class clazz = uc.getClass();
            for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                String name = field.getName();
                Object value;
                try {
                    value = field.get( uc );
                     System.out.printf("Field name: %s, Field value: %s%n", name, value);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
```

My UserClass looks like

```
@Entity
public class UserClass implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String descr;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="userClassId",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<packages> packagesList;
```

I get the UserClass variable names and values normally but the problem is that it also takes some other variables which i dont care about like pcInheritedFieldCount,pcFieldNames and others

My solution is to check if the variable name starts if pc to ignore it but i wanted to know if there is a right/the best way to get only these variables i declared in my class definition.

Comment: "it also takes some other variables" ??? When running your program, I get exactly 5 lines of output, corresponding to the 5 fields you declared in your class. Please make a [mcve].

Comment: You probably tested his program without the @Entity part. I guess spring jpa adds these fields - pcInheritedFieldCount, pcFieldNames  etc

Comment: That's actually a good guess i haven't thought about that it isn't the reflections but the jpa annotation causing the trouble

Comment: I tested it with the dependency to Java EE 7, so I have the annotations at hand. Does Spring JPA change the class file for the class `UserClass`? I thought they are extending the class at runtime.

Comment: I believe they are extending it at runtime. But probably his code is working after spring has done its job and has added these fields. If you just look at the .class file there aren't such fields - just the annotation information. But these pcInheritedFieldCount are part of the PersistingCapable interface and I believe spring has added them to the class runtime. If not run in a spring context it will work properly

Comment: I guess your answer is the solution to my problem on the why this happens. Maybe because i work on Java EE 6 without spring things are done a little differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run this application like that - in a main method and not in some spring context it will work as you expect. The problem is that these JPA anotations when ran in a web application are processed before your code. And what these "markers" do is to mark your classes so the JPA implementation can add behavior to them. That additional behavior is added at runtime and then when you the class information with reflection it is already there.

For a workaround I would suggest you to look for the getter methods instead of iterating through fields. If these are database entities and you want to filter them I guess they will be standard java beans and will have getter for each meaningful property.